# Reference request: Who first proved that right adjoints preserve limits?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, ho.history-overview, adjoint-functors

One of the most famous and unifying theorems in category theory is that [right adjoints preserve limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoints+preserve+%28co-%29limits). I wonder: Who was the first one to prove this fact?

The notion of adjoint functors is, of course, due to Daniel Kan. But I couldn't find the mentioned fact in his paper [*Adjoint Functors*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1958-087-02/S0002-9947-1958-0131451-0/S0002-9947-1958-0131451-0.pdf).

Comment: Peter Freyd both for left and right adjoints in his book abelian Categories, an Introduction to the Theory of Functors its called Freyd's adjoint functor theorem

Comment: I think the adjoint functor theorems are rather a sort of converse to the statement I'm talking about.

Comment: Agreed. This does not answer the question. But, welcome to mathoverflow!

Comment: Whether the citation of Abelian Categories is correct, I don't know, but as I understand it, Peter Freyd is definitely the person who first recognised the unifying notion of "limit". After that, the fact that they are (preseved by) right adjoints is trivial.  So @rft34, as a "new contributor", deserves the "correct answer" bonus.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: Daniel M. Kan defined limits and colimits in his 1956 paper “Adjoint functors” and proved that the (co)limit functor is left/right adjoint to the diagonal functor.  Freyd's earliest paper (his Ph.D. thesis) is from 1960, there is no way he could be credited for (co)limits.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: Additionally, Kan's 1956 paper also explicitly states that left/right adjoint functors preserve (co)limits as Theorems 13.8 and 13.8\*.

Comment: yeah apologies for incorrect answer, her is a quote from the appendix from Freyd's book. "Adjoint functors were defined by Kan [16], who borrowed
their name from functional analysis and who exposed their
properties as outlined in Exercises 3-G and 3-1. Except for
Watts' theorem in 3-N [22], the adjoint functor theorems that
are developed in the rest of the Chapter 3 exercises appeared
in my dissertation [8]."

Answer (score 19):

[Daniel M. Kan](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Daniel+Kan) defined adjoint functors in his paper [Adjoint functors](https://doi.org/10.1090/s0002-9947-1958-0131451-0) (written in 1956).

In Chapter II he defines limits and colimits of arbitrary small diagrams
and proves that the limit and colimit functors
are right and left adjoints to the diagonal functor
in Theorems 7.8 and 8.6.

In Chapter III, he defines the notion of a limit-preserving functor
in Definition 13.1.
In Theorem 13.8 and 13.8* he proves that left/right adjoints preserve (co)limits.

Comment: The implication seems immediate to us now.  But did Kan observe it then?

Comment: @MikeShulman: This is observed explicitly in Chapter III, I added a reference.

Comment: The specific references you give are very helpful/useful for those of us interested in the historical record. Small quibble: your answer currently says 1956 but it seems the paper is from 1958.

Comment: @YemonChoi: The paper states on the first page that it was received by the editors on September 20, 1956, so it is indeed a 1956 paper.  That it took 2 years for the AMS to print it is AMS's problem, not Kan's.  On the other hand, after 65 years, the backlog at AMS journals is even worse now, despite all the improvements in technology.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I saw that, so we are just interpreting or allocating dates in different ways:)
For me, the year of a paper is the year of its publication. (I am happy to say "this is a theorem of Kan from 1956".) As for publishing, I note once again that unlike most very online mathematicians I am at heart a (copy-)editor not a programmer.

Comment: Theorems 13.8 and 13.8* are assuming limit preservation, rather than proving it. In fact, he says that he's proving two functors are adjoint. I don't see that he explicitly proves that right adjoints preserve limits.